# Wayland: Input rotation on touchscreen

Tags: gnome, wayland

I have a new tablet (Eve V), running DebianGnome+Wayland. Screen auto-rotation (using the accelerometer) works perfectly, but the pen input isn't rotated along with the screen output. This makes actually using the thing in portrait mode a bit difficult. ;-)

SO, how do I teach the input driver to flip the input coordinates when rotating?

To clarify: **touch** input **does** rotate OK. The problem is solely the electronic pen.